# math - Calculating impact of violated rules on total files scanned

Tags: math

I have a scenario where I am trying to calculate impact percentage for a programming project (comprising of various files) as follows:

My program analyzes code against some rules that have a weight between 1 to 10. When all files have been analyzed, I have the following statistics available: number of files analyzed, number of rules violated, number of instances of rule violation across all files (per rule), calculated weight per rule (number of instances of rule violation * weight)

Now I need to calculate the impact (in percent) of the rules violation on this project and require a mathematical formula to do so.

Could you please help me formulate this?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you want, is this similar to lint, are error warning and info levels not enough? More info please!

Comment: Hi Alec, my program does not analyze code for lint. it analyzes code for quality, best practices followed or not, docs, comments and many more such areas.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd simply divide your “calculated weight per rule” by the sum of all such weights, and you'd obtain the percentage a single rule contributes to that grand total.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I am not looking for the percentage a single rule contributes to the grand total. I am looking for the impact on the complete project (all files that are analyzed) because of all violated rules. Additionally, as we keep correcting rules and re analyze the code-base, the expectation is to see the impact % reducing. With the formula you mentioned the impact % increases when we are correcting some rules and re-analyzing the code